# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\Path\chromedriver.exe

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, celery

All of a sudden I've started getting this error message, I've been using Selenium and Chromedriver for a while on this project with no issues and as far as I'm aware I've not changed anything to cause this error.

I've read a few posts with this question but haven't been able to solve it.

I've got two projects with the exact same Selenium code, one where I've just got the Selenium part and another that is a full Django project, using Celery to run the Selenium task.

- Chromedriver is working fine still in the selenium-only project (that has exactly the same code and setup as the Django project)
- Chromedriver has been working fine in my Django-Celery project for the past week (when I moved my selenium-only code over to run in celery tasks). I've not changed anything of note in my Django-Celery project to make it stop working
- I've checked and 127.0.0.1 is added to etc/hosts file (it was there already)
- I'm using Windows

I've got no idea what the problem is, this came up a few days ago but then only happened once and went away after I retried, now I can't start Selenium at all.

Comment: Crome driver changed form 96 to 98, did you set driver manualy, or using code?

Comment: I've got ChromeDriver 98.0.4758.102 along with Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit). The ChromeDriver build is Windows 32-bit (there's no 64-bit)

Comment: I set the browser like so: ```browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Path\\chromedriver.exe')```